# Finding percentage from two sum values using query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Data:

[image: data]

Here's the query I have:

```
=QUERY(B4:E,"Select sum(D) where B='"&K4&"' label sum(D)''",0)
```

This works great! (and it is pretty self-explanatory)
Now what I want is to calculate *percentage* in the same query in Col L such as:

> =QUERY(B3:E,"Select **`(sum(D)/sum(E))*100`** where B='"&K3&"' label sum(D)''",0)

Can I not do this percentage thing in one go? How can I perform something like this then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
=QUERY(B2:E,"Select (sum(D)/sum(E))*100 where B='"&K3&"' label (sum(D)/sum(E))*100''",0)
```

and see if that works?

Note that his will calculate the percentage of the sum of both columns. If that is not what you intended try

```
=filter(to_percent(D2:D/E2:E), B2:B=K3))
```

This will output the percent per row (of the rows matching the condition). If you'd want the average of that, then do

```
=average(filter(to_percent(D2:D/E2:E), B2:B=K3))
```

Or, with query

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(B2:E,"Select (D/E*100) where B='"&K3&"' label (D/E*100)''",0))
```

or

```
=TO_PERCENT(AVERAGE(QUERY(B2:E,"Select (D/E) where B='"&K3&"' label (D/E)''",0)))
```

Comment: well, the error has gone. But the output is not correct. It should have returned 65 instead of 153.8... Any explanations for this behavior?

Comment: If I do something like ```Select sum(D)``` or ```Select Sum(E)``` separately, the returned output is correct. but ```(sum(D)/sum(E))``` is somehow not returning correct values.